# Help prove $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is an injection $\Leftrightarrow$ $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a surjection when $|X|=|Y|$

Tags: functions, proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

I need to prove:

> Given non-empty finite sets $X$ and $Y$ with $|X| = |Y|,$ a function $X\rightarrow Y$ is an injection if and only if it is a surjection.

The hint given is to use the pigeonhole principle and proof by contradiction.

Here's what I've tried:

1. From the given assumptions, I know that:

   - $|X|=|Y|=n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$
   - There exist bijections $g:\mathbb{N}_n \rightarrow X$ and $h:\mathbb{N}_n \rightarrow Y$
2. So I need to prove:

   $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is an injection $\Leftrightarrow$ $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a surjection
3. So, to prove the case $\Rightarrow$:

   Suppose for contradiction,

   $f:X\rightarrow Y \text{ is injective but not surjective} \tag{1}$

   Furthermore, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an injection $\Rightarrow |X|\le |Y|$, by the pigeonhole principle.

   This is where I am stuck. I think I need to conclude that $|X|>|Y|$ from $(1)$ so that I can get the contradiction:

   $|X|\le |Y| \text{ and } |X|>|Y|$
4. To prove the case $\Leftarrow$:

   Suppose for contradiction:

   $f:X\rightarrow Y \text{ is surjective but not injective }\tag{ 2}$

   Furthermore,

   $\begin{align} f:X \rightarrow Y \text{ is a surjection } & \Rightarrow & \exists g:Y\rightarrow X \text{ an injection (previous exercise) }\\
   & \Rightarrow & |Y| \le |X|, \text{ pigeonhole principle } \end{align}$

I'm also stuck here. Similar to 3, I think I need to conclude $|Y|>|X|$ from $(2)$ to get a contradiction.

Can I please get some help to complete steps 3 and 4?

Comment: (1) should really read: $ \exists f:X \rightarrow Y  $ injective but not surjective, and similarly for (2). - because the negation of "$P \implies Q $" is " $P$ but not $Q$ "

Answer (score 1):

Before throwing around the pigeonhole principle, just try to reason through a few simple cases. It may help to look at the situation with sets of 4 or 5 elements, and then generalize what you find. Here are some things to think about:

For #3, note that it is impossible to have distinct $a, b \in X$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$. So what does that tell you about the number of elements of $Y$ that are in the image of $f$?

For #4, suppose there are two distinct elements of $X$, say $a$ and $b$, that get mapped to the same $y \in Y$. Then use the surjectivity assumption to count how many elements $X$ must have.

Note that the analogous statement is clearly not true when dealing with sets of the same infinite cardinality (e.g. take $X = \mathbb{N}$ and $Y = \mathbb{N}$, it's easy to come up with a counterexample).

Comment: For #3, this tells me that $|X|<|Y|$, which contradicts $|X|=|Y|$. Correct?

Comment: The argument I have in mind for #3 isn't a proof by contradiction. Think about what the size of the image of $f$ has to be, and compare that to the assumed size of $Y$.

Comment: $|X| = |f(X)| = n$, since $f$ is injective. Also, $|Y|=n$ since we assumed $|X|=|Y|$. But then, this means $|Y|=|f(x)|$ which means $f$ is not surjective. This is still a proof by contradiction...

Comment: There's no contradiction here. You assume that $f$ is injective, and that $|X| = |Y|$. Then arguing as you just did, you find that |Im $f$| = $|X| = |Y|$, so since Im $f \subset Y$ and the sets are all finite it follows that Im $f = Y$. This is a formal way of saying that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: So for #4, can I say: $|\operatorname{Im} f| = |Y|$ because $f$ is assumed to be surjective. Then $|\operatorname{Im} f| = |X|$ because it is assumed $|X|=|Y|$. Hence $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a proof which uses the following version of the pigeonhole principle:

**Pigeonhole Principle:** For each natural number $ n $ and for each proper subset $ Y $ of $\{m\in\mathbb{N}:m<n\}$, $ Y\nsim n $. (page 134 in Elements of Set Theory by Enderton)

In other words, proper subsets of a finite set $A$ are not bijective to $A$.

Sorry for the picture format; it was the best I could do to transfer one of my .tex files with numerous "newcommands" and such into stackexchange.

[image]